# How many records are stored in each offset of kafka partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

I came across the below kafka official statement

For each topic, the Kafka cluster maintains a partitioned log

Each partition is an ordered, immutable sequence of records that is continually appended to—a structured commit log. The records in the partitions are each assigned a sequential id number called the offset that uniquely identifies each record within the partition.

So, Lets say we have a kafka topic called "emprecords" and just assume that  it has only one partition for now and in that partition let's say we have 10 offset starting from 0 to 9

My question is

Does each offset has got the ability to store only one record?

Or

Does each offset has got the ability to store more than one records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each partition, each offset can only be assigned to one record.